# Not able to connect remote git repository through SSH

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have got 2 remote git repositories on the same server. On one repository, I am able to connect properly while on other I am not able to do so. It keeps on asking for password.

I have connected to SSH bby adding ppk key using pageant.

Can anyone help in fixing this. Please let me know what server changes I have to do so that I can make the changes over there.

Comment: What are the URLs for both repositories? Do they use the same user? Is any management software involved to host the repositories? (like gitolite,stash,etc.)

Comment: please check if the same user your are connecting via ssh.